# Scanner and nullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, input, nullpointerexception, java.util.scanner

i don't why i'm getting this exception ! 
my method is very simple it will loop to fill my parallel arrays 
here is my method

```
public void fillPhoneBook(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0;i<this.names.length;i++){
        System.out.println("Enter Name:");
        this.names[i] =in.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Phone Number:");
        this.telephones[i]=in.next();//here start rising exception 
    }
    in.close();
```

i get this exception after the second input !`

**--- UPDATE ---**

sorry the problem was with initializing the telephones array

Comment: Where have you initialized you arrays? Specially `telephones` array?

Comment: Please write your complete class code.

Comment: i've initialize all values in  constructor

Comment: may you please add the initialization code? edit: didnt see you wrote where it occurs. sry.

Comment: Your going to want to use `nextLine` instead of `next`. Thats after you fix the NPE of course.

Comment: sorry guys i've forget to initialize the array , please delete my Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the same scenario as you explained but the strange thing is that I am not getting any such exception. Please have a look at the code below

```
public class TestScanner {
    String names[] = new String[10];
    String telephones[] = new String[10];

    public static void main(String a[]) {

        TestScanner p = new TestScanner();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < p.names.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Name:");
            p.names[i] = in.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Phone Number:");
            p.telephones[i] = in.next();// here start rising exception
        }
        in.close();

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter Name:
test1
Enter Phone Number:
123456
Enter Name:
test2
Enter Phone Number:
456789
Enter Name:
```

Comment: i think he failed initializing it properly. thats what you did locally here.

Comment: Thats what I wrote in the comment of the code that please write the complete code so that we can solve the problem.